# Flask-SQLAlchemy get rows with non-zero count

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following two models in my database:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    websites = db.relationship('Website', backref='category', lazy='dynamic')

class Website(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    url = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    class_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

What I now want to do is write an expression for loading all the categories that have one or more websites associated with them. In SQL I can achieve this with a `join` and `having`, but I'm having trouble translating it into SQLAlchemy.

I first tried to import and use `func`, but then realized that it's not defined in Flask-SQLAlchemy. My next try was `Category.query.having(Category.websites.count() > 1).all()` but this gives me an error that `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Category.websites has an attribute 'count'`. What's the right way to do this?

Any help will be appreiciated!

Comment: Your attribute is called `websites`, not `wesbites`.

Comment: @dirn Thanks a lot! I still get an error, though. Have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can still use join with group_by() and the having() func. Here's an example [taken from the docs for having() that might be what you're looking for:](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html)

```
q = session.query(Website.id).\
            join(Website.category_id).\
            group_by(Category.id).\
            having(func.count(Website.url) > 0)
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do with Flask-SQLAlchemy? I don't want to use SQLAlchemy as it might cause problems later for not being aware of my app/

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy is just a wrapper around SQLAlchemy. `Website.query` is just a convenience that wraps the session. There's nothing wrong with using the session directly.